# How to truncate certain text in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have following INPUT out.

```
pieChart.js
stackedColumnChart.js
table.js
```

and i want OUTPUT like that(wanna remove .js from )

```
pieChart
stackedColumnChart
table
```

Comment: what's the input? Please add more javascript around it. String? Array of Strings? File?

Comment: ``"pieChart.js".split(".")[0]; // "pieChart" `` - a really primitive way

Answer (score 3):

```
var array = ['pieChart.js', 'stackedColumnChart.js', 'table.js'];

var modifiedArray = array.map(function(el) {
  return el.replace('.js', '');
});

console.log(modifiedArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

If input is a multi-line string:

```
var input = "pieChart.js\n" +
"stackedColumnChart.js\n" +
"table.js";

var output = input.replace(/\.js$/mg, '');
```

If it's an array:

```
var input = ["pieChart.js","stackedColumnChart.js","table.js"];
var output = $.map(input, function(el){
    return el.replace(/\.js$/, '');
});
```

Comment: you'll have to use multiline. `input.replace(/\.js$/mg, "")`

Answer (score 0):

You just substring the characters except the last 3

```
var dotJS = "pieChart.js";
var withoutJS = dotJS.substr(0,dotJS.length-3);

alert (withoutJS);
```

Now you have a string minus those last three characters.

(pffft...  Wow, I'm late with my answer here.)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the strings and take substring of those strings.

In this case :

```
var array = ['pieChart.js', 'stackedColumnChart.js', 'table.js'];

for (item in array){
    newItem = item.substr(0, item.length-3);
    console.log(newItem);
}
```